Powershell SDK accessing values of Powershell objects?
Hello All I'm new to C# and .NET programming.  I am trying to take a powershell script and make an agent that performs the similar function. The agent compiles and installs correctly and logs the output of the powershell commands to a log file.  The problem is that I am not accessing the values but rather the log prints the object out?  How can I access the values? Thanks in advance and be gentle with my rudimentary attempt.
My reference to the documentation I have been using:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0
Log file output:
Execution Time: 10/2/2024 3:49:45 PM Launched Bandwidth Trap...System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
Code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace SBC_Agent
{
     public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
     {
          Timer timer = new Timer(); // name space(using System.Timers;)
          private Timer _audittimer;
          private string auditFilePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\Audit";

          public Service1()
          {
               InitializeComponent();
          }
          protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
          {
               WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
               timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
               timer.Interval = 5000; //number in milliseconds
               timer.Enabled = true;

               _audittimer = new Timer();
               _audittimer.Interval = 60000;
               _audittimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedAuditTime);
               _audittimer.Enabled = true;

               Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(auditFilePath));
          }
          private void OnElapsedAuditTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
          {
               RunPowerShellCommands();
          }

          private void BandwidthTrap()
          {
               try
               {
                    using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell psInstance = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                         //psInstance.AddScript("Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ip4routetable | where {$_.destination -eq \"0.0.0.0\"} | select -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex | select -First 1");
                         psInstance.AddScript("Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ip4routetable");
                         var int_index = psInstance.Invoke();
                         //var ifIndex = "InterfaceIndex=" + int_index;
                         using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(auditFilePath, true))
                         {
                              writer.WriteLine("Execution Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Launched Bandwidth Trap..." + int_ndex);
                         }
                    }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Powershell Service Error: " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(auditFilePath, true))
                    {
                         writer.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                         writer.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
                    }
               }      
          }
          private void RunPowerShellCommands()
          {
               try
               {

                    BandwidthTrap();
                    /*
                    using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell psInstance = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                         psInstance.AddScript("Get-Process");
                         var results = psInstance.Invoke();
                         using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(auditFilePath, true))
                         {
                              writer.WriteLine("Execution Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                              foreach (var result in results)
                              {
                                   writer.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                              }
                              writer.WriteLine();
                         }
                    }
                    */
               }
               catch (Exception ex) 
               {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Powershell Service Error: " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(auditFilePath, true))
                    {
                         writer.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                         writer.WriteLine("StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
                    }
               }
               
          }
          protected override void OnStop()
          {
               WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
          }
          private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
          {
               WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);
          }
          public void WriteToFile(string Message)
          {
               string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
               if (!Directory.Exists(path)) 
               {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
               }
               string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
               if (!File.Exists(filepath))
               {
                    //Create a file to write to
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
                    {
                         sw.WriteLine(Message);
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}


Original script:
$HOSTNAME=hostname
$RXKEY="bandwidth_rx_trap"
$TXKEY="bandwidth_tx_trap"

$ifIndex = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ip4routetable | where {$_.destination -eq "0.0.0.0"} | select -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex | select -First 1
$ifIndex = "InterfaceIndex=" + $ifIndex
$nic_name = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter $ifIndex | select -ExpandProperty Description
$nic = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Networkinterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | where {($_.description -eq $nic_name) -and ($_.operationalstatus -eq "up")}


for ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++){
   $bytesSent = 0
   $bytesReceived = 0
   $stats = $nic.GetIPv4Statistics()
   $bytesSent = $stats.BytesSent
   $bytesReceived = $stats.BytesReceived
   $bytesSentSum = $bytesSentSum + $bytesSent
   $bytesReceivedSum = $bytesReceivedSum + $bytesReceived
   Start-Sleep 1
}

$TXAVG=[math]::round($bytesSentSum/5/1024,0)
$RXAVG=[math]::round($bytesReceivedSum/5/1024,0)


What are you looking to extract from Get-Process and why are you using a PSInstance and Get-Process to begin with instead of using Process.GetProcesses() ?

The full command I'm trying to get output from is this: ("Get-WmiObject -Class win32_ip4routetable | where {$_.destination -eq "0.0.0.0"} | select -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex | select -First 1"
I added the script to the original post that I'm trying to recreate.

@SantiagoSquarzon Compiler version '4.11.0-3.24376.4 (5e3a11e2)'. Language version: 7.3.

If you want to extract the first InterfaceIndex from win32_ip4routetable it's easier to use the Invoke<T>() method, then the method outputs a Collection<T> instead of a Collection<PSObject>, then from there you can FirstOrDefault() it pretty easily.
In summary:
using (PowerShell psInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    int int_index = psInstance
        .AddScript(@"
            Get-CimInstance -Class win32_ip4routetable |
                Where-Object { $_.Destination -eq '0.0.0.0' } |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex -First 1")
        .Invoke<int>()
        .FirstOrDefault();

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(auditFilePath, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(
            $"Execution Time: {DateTime.Now} Launched Bandwidth Trap...{int_index}");
    }
}

You could also use ManagementObjectSearcher class directly, no PowerShell instance needed:
string query = @"
SELECT InterfaceIndex FROM Win32_IP4RouteTable
WHERE Destination='0.0.0.0'";

ManagementObject? result = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
    .Get()
    .OfType<ManagementObject>()
    .FirstOrDefault();

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(auditFilePath, true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(
        $"Execution Time: {DateTime.Now} Launched Bandwidth Trap...{result?["InterfaceIndex"]}");
}


You are a genius, a scholar, and a gentleman. My thanks!

glad it helped @PatrickCarra, thanks for the kind words. you can choose to accept the answer if it helped answering the question

I wish I could but I don't have enough reputation.  Can you help with that? I think by voting for my question (confirming it was good) would help with that!  I want to contribute more to the community but need to raise my reputation to be able to do that.

Mmmm but you don't need reputation to accept an answer, anyone asking a question can do that by simply clicking on the "tick" button as shown here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/962245

Accepting and voting are two different things. I learned something new today. Thanks!

Awesome @PatrickCarra I've upvoted your question too so you can upvote future answers  :)
